# Formatting the prompt when using the input function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm trying to write a script that will prompt a user for an answer to an addition problem. To do this I need to pass a variable to the string that is displayed during the prompt but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.

I've come up with the following code that does not work:

```
operand = 4
ans = input('What is 4 + {0} ?') .format(operand)
```

returns:

```
'What is 4 + {0} ?'
```

But I want it to be:

```
'What is 4 + 4 ?'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ans = input('What is 4 + {0} ?'.format(operand))
```

You need to modify the string argument to input.  In your code you are trying to format the input string returned by the `input` function

Answer (score 2):

format is a method on the string, so like so:

```
ans = input('What is 4 + {0} ?'.format(operand))
```